# 401 unauthorized when login to manage my app

Tags: tomcat, authentication, user-roles

I have downloaded tomcat7 ZIP file. After unzip the folder, I went to **Tomcat7.0/conf/** directory, and edit the **tomcat-users.xml** to:

```
<tomcat-users>  
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>  
  <role rolename="role1"/>  
  <role rolename="manager"/>  
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>  
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>  
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>  

  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager,tomcat,role1"/>  

</tomcat-users>
```

Then, I started my tomcat, on tomcat web page, I clicked on the "**Manager App**" button, which popped up a login dialog. I input username "**admin**" and password "**admin**" , but I got **401 unauthorized** error. Why? What is wrong in my *tomcat-users.xml* configuration?

Answer (score 3):

The required role is called `manager-gui` as per http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access

Answer (score 1):

Quote from `http://localhost:8080/manager/html`

> ```
> <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
> <user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui"/>
> ```
>
> Note that for Tomcat 6.0.30 onwards, the roles required to use the
>   manager application were changed from the single manager role to the
>   following four roles.
>
> ```
> manager-gui - allows access to the HTML GUI and the status pages
> manager-script - allows access to the text interface and the status pages
> manager-jmx - allows access to the JMX proxy and the status pages
> manager-status - allows access to the status pages only
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is because from Tomcat 7.0 onwards, you need to add the below four roles to your tomcat-users.xml

NOTE: I am using Tomcat 8.5.9

\conf\tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <user roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status" username="tomcat" password="******"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give role name as manager-gui... It will give permission to access manage app page...

Answer (score 0):

If using Eclipse WTP to manage Tomcat, be careful because Eclipse actually makes copy of configuration files in Server project in Workspace.